# проблема с конвертированием изображения php

Tags: php

здравствуйте, у меня есть класс изображений, и есть функция которая конвертирует png изображения в jpg

```
            case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);
            $path = $this->createdir().str_shuffle(substr(md5($tmp), 0, 20)).'.jpg';
            imagejpeg($image, $this->cdndir.$path, 100);
            imagedestroy($image);
            break;
```

но дело в том, что при конверте, если у изображения есть прозрачный фон, то он заменяется ужасными разноцветными оттенками, или же просто черным цветом, как можно сделать замену прозрачного фона на белый цвет?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно создать изображение с белым фоном и поместить png поверх него:

```
$image = imagecreatefrompng($tmp);
$bg = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagefill($bg, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($bg, 255, 255, 255));
imagealphablending($bg, TRUE);
imagecopy($bg, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
imagedestroy($image);
imagejpeg($bg, $здесьвашpath, 100);
imagedestroy($bg);
```

Ответ [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201798/use-php-to-convert-png-to-jpg-with-compression)